# New Azure SQL Database Services, how scalable and what are DTUs

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

The new new Azure SQL Database Services look good. However I am trying to work out how scalable they really are.

So, for example, assume a 200 concurrent user system.

For Standard

```
Workgroup and cloud applications with "multiple" concurrent transactions
```

For Premium

```
Mission-critical, high transactional volume with "many" concurrent users
```

What does "Multiple" and "Many" mean?

Also Standard/S1 offers 15 DTUs while Standard/S2 offers 50 DTUs. What does this mean?

Going back to my 200 user example, what option should I be going for?

[Azure SQL Database Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dn741340.aspx)

Thanks

EDIT

[Useful page on definitions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn741336.aspx)

However what is "max sessions"? Is this the number of concurrent connections?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is really hard to tell without doing a test. By 200 users I assume you mean 200 people sitting at their computer at the same time doing stuff, not 200 users who log on twice a day. S2 allows 49 transactions per second which sounds about right, but you need to test. Also doing a lot of caching can't hurt.

Comment: Thanks for this. Yes I do mean this, and I agree with the testing. I use JMeter. What does "Max Sessions" mean? It sort of looks like number of connections, anyway the more you pay the more you get. Just wondered whether this was linked to concurrency.

Comment: I think Max Session corresponds to Max Connections. Considering you normally use connection pooling so it doesn't correspond to users.

Comment: I wonder what are the "Max Sessions" for the current Web SQL Database offering, which we use. Yes connection pooling would be used, by default in a EF/MSSQL setup I guess. So if the "Max Session" number was low, then queries would be queuing up a lot. Can they timeout and fail?

Comment: So I guess a 200 Max Session account (Standard/S1) would probably meet expectations for a 400 concurrent user requirement, with pooling. Just thinking aloud..... Also assuming no very slow SQL.

Comment: I would think so, but you really need to test because every app is different.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I appreciate the need for testing, just trying to get my head around the concepts.

Answer (score 4):

There are some great MSDN articles on Azure SQL Database, this one in particular has a great starting point for DTUs.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn741336.aspx and http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Azure-Storage-SQL-Database-Tutorials/Scott-Klein-Video-02

In short, it's a way to understand the resources powering each performance level.  One of the things we know when talking with Azure SQL Database customers, is that they are a varied group.  Some are most comfortable with the most absolute details, cores, memory, IOPS - and others are after a much more summarized level of information.  There is no one-size fits all.  DTU is meant for this later group.

Regardless, one of the benefits of the cloud is that it's easy to start with one service tier and performance level and iterate.  In Azure SQL Database specifically you can change the performance level while you're application is up. During the change there is typically less than a second of elapsed time when DB connections are dropped.  The internal workflow in our service for moving a DB from service tier/performance level follows the same pattern as the workflow for failing over nodes in our data centers.  And nodes failing over happens all the time independent of service tier changes.  In other words, you shouldn’t notice any difference in this regard relative to your past experience.

If DTU's aren't your thing, we also have a more detailed benchmark workload that may appeal.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn741327.aspx

Thanks Guy

Comment: Guy, Really appreciate your feedback. One of the issues we are getting at the moment is very variable query performance. We currently use SQL Database Web, and our user base is not large, and the database is new, MBs in size. I have seen the Membership Service GetUser SP vary from 1 sec to 4 sec(as measured by NewRelic on the SQL layer). I am a little suspicious that I may be suffering some form of contention in the DB hence the variability. Thus I have hopes that the new Standard S1 will be more performant.

Comment: Just looked at your last link. Useful, however I am unsure why different throughput units are used ie transaction/hour, transaction/minute and transaction/sec. Why not express it all with the same unit ie transaction/sec. Also it would be most interesting to specify the current SQL Database Web and business instance. One would hope to see a big increase over SQL Database Web. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Check out the new [Elastic DB](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-elastic-pool-portal/) offering (Preview) announced at Build today. The [pricing page](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/sql-database/) has been updated with Elastic DB price information.

Answer (score 0):

DTUs are based on a blended measure of CPU, memory, reads, and writes. As DTUs increase, the power offered by the performance level increases. Azure has different limits on the concurrent connections, memory, IO and CPU usage. Which tier one has to pick really depends upon

1. #concurrent users
2. Log rate
3. IO rate
4. CPU usage
5. Database size

For example, if you are designing a system where multiple users are reading and there are only a few writers, and if your application middle tier can cache the data as much as possible and only selective queries / application restart hit the database then you may not worry too much about the IO and CPU usage.

If many users are hitting the database at the same time, you may hit the concurrent connection limit and requests will be throttled. If you can control user requests coming to the database in your application then this shouldn't be a problem.

Log rate: Depends upon the volume of the data changes (including additional data pumping in the system). I have seen application steadily pumping the data vs data being pumped all at once. Selecting the right DTU again depends upon how one can do throttling at the application end and get steady rate.

Database size: Basic, standard, and premium has different allowed max sizes, and this is another deciding factor. Using table compression kind of features helps reducing the total size, and hence total IO.

Memory: Tuning the expesnive queries (joins, sorts etc),  enabling lock escalation / nolock scans help controlling the memory usage.

The very common mistake people usually do in database systems is scaling up their database instead of tuning the queries and application logic. So testing, monitoring the resources / queries with different DTU limits is the best way of dealing this.

**If choose the wrong DTU, don't worry you can always scale up/ down in SQL DB and it is completely online operation**

Also unless a strong reason migrate to V12 to get even better performance and features.